# Communication of errors between threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a question ID someone can help me please, I have a list of IP addresses and in each time a use one address to send some requests using python threads.
the problem is I don't know how I can switch between the IPs when any exception is raised.

For example, I have 5 threads and the exception is raised first in thread 4, so it will change the IP address by incrementing the iteration index the problem is when the other threads will face the same the exception they will not use the same address as thread 4.

```
def fct(elm,IP):
   do work
   if ip is not valid:
   raise invalid_IP

jobs = Queue()


def do_stuff(q,Ip_adress):
    while not q.empty():
        try:
            value = q.get()
            fct(item=value,IP)
            q.task_done()
        except invalid_IP:
            #move to the next IP and retry


for i in lines:
    jobs.put(i)
Ip_adress = [IP1,IP2]
for i in range(5):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(jobs,Ip_adress))
    worker.start()

jobs.join()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you have that *doesn't* switch between IPs when an exception is raised.

Comment: What exactly does switching between the IPs mean? Same for moving to the next IP and retrying. When you `get()` an item from a `Queue`, it's removed, so what's getting retried?

Comment: the idea is that I should use the list of the IPs addresses to send request, so what should I retry is `the fct(elm,IP)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I really understand what you're trying to accomplish, so have made a number of assumptions and arrived at the following solution. To have something to test with, I more or less took the pseudocode in your question and modified it in order to have something runnable I could use. If my assumptions were invalid then this answer will likely be, too.

Errors are "communicated" indirectly by having each thread update the `ip_addresses` list and remove the offending IP when one occurs and try to get another one to retry with. This of course can't continue if there aren't any more of them—at which time a fatal `RuntimeError` is raised to help further processing.

The tricky part was updating the list of IP address shared among the threads in a way that wouldn't corrupt the data. I also added a `results` list that is print out at the end to show which items that were processed and in what order — something strictly optional and not an essential part of the solution.

```
from random import randrange, uniform
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep
import threading


IP1,IP2 = '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2'
LINES = [f'line #{i}' for i in range(1, 11)]
N = 2  # Reciprocal value of N determines probability of invalid ip.


class Invalid_IP(Exception):
    pass

def fct(elm, ip):
    sleep(uniform(.1, 1))
    if randrange(N) % N == 0:
       raise Invalid_IP(ip)

def do_stuff(q, r, ip_addresses):
    ip = ip_addresses[0]

    while not q.empty():
        item = q.get()
        while True:
            try:
                fct(item, ip)
            except Invalid_IP:
                with listlock:
                    try:
                        ip_addresses.remove(ip)
                    except ValueError:
                        pass  # Already removed by another thread.
                    try:
                        ip = ip_addresses[0]  # Get next ip addresses.
                    except IndexError as exc:
                        raise RuntimeError('No more IPs') from exc

            break  # Job done.
        q.task_done()
        r.put(item)


listlock = threading.Lock()  # To protect concurrent access to following list.
ip_addresses = [IP1, IP2]
jobs = Queue()
results = Queue()

for i in LINES:
    jobs.put(i)

for i in range(5):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(jobs, results, ip_addresses))
    worker.start()

jobs.join()
print('results')
while not results.empty():
    print(f'  {results.get()}')

print('-fini-')
```

Comment: can you explain why you are using the N?

Comment: It's just a simple way to control how often an IP will be considered invalid in the simulation. i.e. `N` = 2 → 1/2, `N` = 3 → 1/3, etc. It's part of the test-bed and has nothing to do with how the "communication" is being done — it's only to make failures occur a probabilistic number of times.

Comment: Ah, I see i ll test your logic and let you know, really thank you for your help